# Black background screen, while showing a popup view, using a separate UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a `UIViewController`, which is embedded in a `UINavigationController`. In that view controller I have a `UIButton`, which shows a popup view, which is another `UIViewController` (pVC). It does that via a `segue`, which is set to `showModally`. Inside the popup I just have a single `UIView`.

Now, I'm setting the background colour of my pVC to clear, so when the button is tapped, it creates the effect like only the view inside pVC appears.

The problem is, when I set the background colour of pVC to `clear` and tap the button, pVC appears as intended on top of my current `view controller`, but after a second, the background becomes black. Here how it looks like:

[image]

In a `View Hierarchy Debugger` I see that this is a `UIWindow` layer that becomes black. I wonder, maybe this happens because my previous `view controller` is embedded inside a `UINavigationController`? When I try to do the same with two `UIViewControllers`, none of which is embedded inside anything, it works fine.

If you know the exact reason why this happens and/or how to solve the issue, I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to show modally `pVC` over the current context, doing so:

[image]

---

about [overCurrentContext](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle/1621507-overcurrentcontext):

> The views beneath the presented content are not removed from the view hierarchy when the presentation finishes. *So if the presented view controller does not fill the screen with opaque content, the underlying content shows through.*

Comment: So, the reason of the black background was that the views beneath the new  view controller were removed from the view hierarchy?

Comment: Exactly, they won't be rendered

Comment: @TigranIskandaryan You can set Kind and Presentation on either the Segue or on the view controller. I would recommend setting it on the view controller.

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini, could you explain why you prefer setting it on the view controller itself?

Comment: @TigranIskandaryan I do think Adrian suggested that.

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini, sorry :)

Comment: @Adrian, could you explain why you prefer setting it on the view controller itself?

Comment: It's a stylistic thing, but I find it's less prone to problems down the road if you  delete a segue.

Answer (score 1):

Change background color of popup view to transparent in stead and do segue like this

Also add this code to the viewController that presents the popup and change name of segue to yours with selecting modally in storyboard with/without animation

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "showLogout")
    {

         let newVC = segue.destination;

        self.setPresentationStyleForSelfController(selfController: self,presentingController: newVC)


    }
  }

func setPresentationStyleForSelfController(selfController:UIViewController,presentingController:UIViewController)
{
   if #available(iOS 8.0, *)
    {

        //iOS 8.0 and above

        presentingController.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true;

        presentingController.definesPresentationContext = true;

        presentingController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext




    }
    else
    {

         presentingController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.currentContext

        selfController.navigationController?.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.currentContext
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but couldn't the same be achieved from the storyboard by changing the presentation style?